# Client side http proxy in ruby

Tags: windows, ruby, proxy

What is a good approach to a client proxy written in ruby that I can use to create a custom filter.

So far I've found

- [Ruby Proxy using webrick](http://www.freedomcoder.com.ar/?p=148)
- [Mousehole, a scriptable Ruby proxy](http://github.com/whymirror/mousehole) by _why (UPDATE this was not robust)

A little on the fringe, this guy wants to [Use rack as thin proxy](http://groups.google.com/group/thin-ruby/browse_thread/thread/6fcb3a603b51c755) with his question.  I don't think he got an answer; or even a hint that it was possible.

What is your advice on these suggested approaches or do you have a better approach.

Thanks!

Comment: do you want a full fledged http proxy or just a socket connector? (I assume the former)

Comment: I would like to be able to monitor http requests and answer questions like "how long did I spend on StackOverflow today"

Comment: A bonus would be the ability to restrict use if it exceeded a preset time goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can’t speak on personal experience as I’ve not done this myself, but I have heard of mouseHole before and it seems to be a good package. Why not try writing a simple script for it and see how you find it?

There are also some [sample scripts](http://github.com/whymirror/mousehole/blob/master/samples/coral.rb) in that repository that you could check out.

Comment: I got mouseHole running - it proxied sites like Google, but crashed on sites like YouTube StackOverflow & Facebook   thx

Comment: While I can't advocate using Mousehole as a forward client side web proxy, it is the only example of how to use Mongrel as this type of proxy.  Unlike Webrick the Mongrel proxy is capable of streaming.  I did not however find this to be the best route.  Ultimately, I went with squid with an external_acl_type to a ruby script.